# Merge two first and second elements in ArrayBuffer

Tags: arrays, scala

I have these ArrayBuffers:

```
ArrayBuffer(1.0, $, monitor, fine, couple, week, develop, expo)
ArrayBuffer(2.0, $, latest, company, follow, mercedes, unreliable, territory)
ArrayBuffer(5.0, $, plan, everyday, continually, surprised, fault)
ArrayBuffer(2.0, $, work, box, broken, turn, turn, seconds, very, frustrating) 
ArrayBuffer(7.0, $, wait, deliver, wait, deliver, doesnt, bode, well, sony)
...
```

and i want to make below strings from these ArrayBuffers:

```
1.0$ monitor fine couple week develop expo
2.0$ latest company follow mercedes unreliable territory
5.0$ plan everyday continually surprised fault
2.0$ work box broken turn turn seconds very frustrating
7.0$ wait deliver wait deliver doesnt bode well sony
...
```

and i've tried:

```
val ArrBuf1 = ArrayBuffer.map(_.mkString(" "))
val out = ArrBuf1.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

but my code shows these results:

```
1.0 $ monitor fine couple week develop expo
2.0 $ latest company follow mercedes unreliable territory
5.0 $ plan everyday continually surprised fault
...
```

How can i merge two first and second elements in these Arraybuffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
_.mkString(" ")
```

with:

```
l => l.head + l.tail.mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you incase you need to merge any field of the collection

code:-

```
var x =List(ArrayBuffer(1.0, "$"," monitor"," fine"," couple"," week"," develop", "expo"),
ArrayBuffer(2.0, "$"," latest"," company"," follow"," mercedes"," unreliable"," territory"),
ArrayBuffer(5.0, "$"," plan"," everyday"," continually"," surprised"," fault"),
ArrayBuffer(2.0, "$"," work"," box"," broken"," turn"," turn"," seconds"," very"," frustrating"),
ArrayBuffer(7.0, "$"," wait"," deliver"," wait"," deliver"," doesnt"," bode"," well"," sony"))

var mergerAtFeild=1
x.foreach { x => x.zipWithIndex.foreach{
    f=>{
     print(if(f._2 == mergerAtFeild){f._1.toString()}else{" "+f._1.toString()})
    }
}
 print("\n")
}
```